# How can I specify a location when searching in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, search

Don't tell me "navigate to the place and type in search box", no that's not what I want.

And certainly I wont first perform a non-hit search and click on "custom...".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like the way Windows Search works you might want to have a look at these links:

[Can I restore the XP style search to Windows 7?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/can-i-restore-the-xp-style-search-to-windows-7/e1601f87-8aa8-4992-b46e-562071aa1e7e)

https://superuser.com/questions/135423/whats-a-good-alternative-to-windows-search-for-files-and-folders

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm not using Windows Search. I just want to first specify a search location when using Win+F in Windows 7, like I can in Windows Vista. But this seems to be impossible now. Thanks anyway.